# How does water move out of the way/around an object moving under water?

Tags: forces, water, turbulence

Let's say a torpedo moved under the water. Water is virtually in-compressible right? So what happens to the water in front of the torpedo as it pushes forward?  It has to somehow move out of the way, so where does it go?

Does it get pushed up? How can it get pushed if there is feet of water above it. Does it get push up and around, filling in the water behind its path?

I don't mean to get detailed with mathematics. I am just curious where and how the water is moved out of the way as a swimmer, object etc is moving through the water.

Thank you

Comment: "virtually" is not the same as "totally".  If you imagine a stationary torpedo being initially lowered into a large tank of  water, it will displace water in the direction of least density, i.e. upwards towards the surface.

Comment: Okay but as it moves forward now in the tank, where does  water go? All around it? Depending on how deep it is, seems it would take alot of force to make the water move up. Which is suppose is why nothing moves easily underwater

Comment: Related, though it doesn't answer your question:   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196013/breaking-the-sound-barrier-underwater/196019#196019 I would guess that any disturbance in water, in any direction would eventually be dissapated by a slight rise in the surface level.